# Method attempt does not exist in Lumen

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, lumen

I am making an API using Lumen and Fractal, but I got an error

> Method attempt does not exist

while trying to login. Can somebody help me to solve this? This is my controller:

```
public function login(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if (!Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password'  => $request->password])) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'email or password wrong'], 401);
    }

    $user = $user->find(Auth::user()->id);

    return fractal()
        ->item($user)
        ->transformWith(new UserTransformer)
        ->addMeta([
            'token' => $user->api_token,
        ])
        ->toArray();
}
```

this is my error

(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method attempt does not exist.
in Macroable.php (line 74)

Comment: Hi Easy learn did you got any solution to get that fixed, I am facing same issue using using Lumen 5.5

Comment: Method attempt doesn't exist, You can use check method instead of attempt.

Comment: can you show me your user model? You need to actually implement those methods defined by the contract. Use the Authenticatable trait.

Answer (score -1):

in your bootstrap/app.php file did you uncomment either of these lines around line 26 or around lines 81-83?

```
// $app->withFacades();

// $app->withEloquent();
```